# When use socket to fetch http response, how to ensure to end the read?

Tags: java, sockets, http

When I use socket to send http request and read the response, I use a buffer to read the response in loop. 
When should I complete the read in every request?

Comment: When you've received `content-length` bytes of content.

Comment: @JimGarrison But some response has only http head, and no `content-length`

Comment: You will have to post examples of the _responses_ that you are having trouble with.  Otherwise your question is probably off-topic.

Comment: So the content length is zero, so you should read zero bytes of body. If you're implementing HTTP you need a good knowledge of RFC 2616, especially the parts about content-length and the `Connection: keepalive/close` header.